# Admob ads not showing in my react native app

Tags: react-native, admob, ads

I am using admob in my react native app, I created an admob successfully and created an ad unit, but no ads are showing up and getting, "The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory", but test ads are working properly. There are similar questions here but some of them old and some are not clear.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably using the package `react-native-admob`. There are 2 things you need to understand.

1. Newly created add unit will take a little time to load ads. It may be 24 hours or 2-3 days.
2. You have to submit your information to verify your payment details in adsense before they start serving admob ads.

Comment: yes thanks it is working right now, i am trying to only show house ad campaings in my app do you have any information about that?

Comment: In the admob settings you can block or allow ads of different categories..
check that.. it may help you.. 
if the answer was good please mark it as accepted.